# What's the difference between header tag and plain div?

Tags: html, css

Since, all HTML elements will be customized by the CSS, what's the difference between using HTML elements like `<nav>` and `<header>` versus just using `<div>`

Comment: Its called semantic. Each HTMLElement have their own features which can become useful somewhere in the future. Moreover reading `header` gives me idea that it is a header than reading `div`

Answer (score 0):

It's basically semantic ... it provides a readable structure and layout to your document. Easier to read / debug / construct

Comment: It does make code readability easier. So that's all it is. But they hold no access to particular functionality?

Comment: Depends on what you mean be functionality? It's also important for rendering the page since browsers "should" follow W3 standards

Answer (score 0):

It is for Symantec purposes and also when you select the best tag it is helpful in SEO , if you work on a team it is better to use these tags so you can understand each other

Comment: You mean "semantic". Symantec is a security company.

Comment: thank you for this explanation it was a syntax error.